# Record button is missing from Chrome DevTools for NodeJS CPU profiling

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

I was trying to use **Chrome DevTools** as usual for recording **NodeJS CPU profiling**, but this time something was different that there wasn't a record button inside the **Profiler** property page.

As you can see from the image below, the property page is entirely empty.

[missing profiler record button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xW3s.png)

The software's versions are shown below:

*chrome*: `Version 87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

*node*: `10.14.2`

*OS*: `Ubuntu 20.04`

Does anyone know what is going on? Or, is there an alternative way of profiling NodeJS performance without using Chrome DevTools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with a similar setup but with Kubuntu 19.10.

I rolled back chrome to its previous version (86.0.4240.75) which I got here:  https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/download-chrome.php?file=files%2F86.0.4240.75%2Fgoogle-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb.

This got me back my CPU Profiler.

Comment: Thanks, It really helps.

Answer (score 6):

This is a Chrome bug in v87+ and a fix is pending release: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151855